# Kendo UI combo-box virtualization issue with small set of local data

Tags: jquery, angularjs, combobox, kendo-ui

Combo box is not loading the items after filtering it.

The issue is with around 10-60 items(small set of data).

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Filter an item(eg.: ZIORE) from text box.
2. Open the combo box using mouse.
3. Scroll down and see the items.
4. Loading... text is persist for ever.

```html
    <div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
             <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                <select kendo-combo-box
           ng-model="product.selectedproduct"
           k-placeholder="'Select product'"
           k-data-text-field="'product'"
           k-data-value-field="'productId'"
           k-data-source="productsDataSource"
           k-index="0"
           k-filter="'contains'"
           k-virtual="productsVirtualOptions"
           k-height="200">
                </select>
             </div>
         </div>
```

I have demonstrated the issue in plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OBt8kJCDMeCUSbhQm1LV?p=preview

Please provide a solution.

Comment: This is fixed in the latest kendo http://plnkr.co/edit/vHFmfn?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in the latest kendo version.

include the latest version of kendo.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.default.min.
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vHFmfn?p=preview